# Informatica Source File Name with Special Character like 'ä'

Tags: informatica, flat-file

I am having a problem with my source file name when loading a source from list file. My file is named: "Bär.csv" but when executing, this error occurs. It can't find my file as it was changed to "BÃ¶r.csv". Is there a way for the reader to read special characters in the file name?

Error opening file [C:\Informatica\10.2.0\server\infa_shared\SrcFiles\Inbound\test\BÃ¶r.csv].  Operating system error message [The system cannot find the file specified.].

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your integration service to use Unicode.

Comment: Is it _datamovementmode_ under **Properties** or _codepage_ under **Processes**?

Comment: datamovementmode is set to **Unicode** and the codepage is set to **MS Window Latin 1 (ANSI)**